# Compiling C# code with CSC - excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am struggling with the following error when compiling my C# code with CSC - "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exits in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly)"

I've had zero experience with object oriented programming before tackling this project.  It involves automation of a couple devices through serial commands.  Parameters are read from a native Excel file and data is written to Excel files that the code creates.

Here's what think maybe pertinent:

- my compiling command: CSC /r:"C:\Data\Code\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" compiled.cs
- I have the file Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll in the directory above.  I found the file on my computer from something else that installed it.  It is dated 2007.
- I am using Office 2010
- I installed Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable but can't tell what that did
- I am referencing CSC from Framework (not Framework64) revision 4.0.30319
- Here is the header to my code

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.IO.Ports;
  using System.Threading;
  using Microsoft.Office.Core;
  using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

  namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)

Follow-up question (if I get this working) what things do I need to worry about to make this run on another computer?  My thoughts was that all I needed was the .excel.dll and the .exe file in the same directory structure?  (At this time I don't know what version of .NET or Office is being run on the target computer - my guess would be at least it would be Office 2010.)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I've been wearing out google on this one for the past week+

Regards,
Keith

Comment: I tried editing your post to do proper code formatting but it does not want to let me do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the exact answer you're looking for, but I'm posting it because I think it would be more helpful  than directly answering your question.

You would save yourself a LOT of time by downloading Visual C# 2010 Express and letting the IDE do the heavy lifting for you.

It sounds like you need to add a reference, which means referencing an existing .dll file somewhere.  I know if can be done via the command line, but it's a LOT easier to use the IDE.

It's free, and can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

There's a How-To guide for Office Interop here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: David,  I guess I did miss one detail I was using Visual C# 2010 Express to write and test the code.  I figured the compiled .exe version would be a little easier / straightforward for others to use.  I'll check out the How-to-guide - thanks.

Comment: @user1086255 - The fact you cannot even compile your own software manually should tell you its not easier then simply only providing a VS solution.